# Removing duplicates in a list (Python 3.8.3)

Tags: python-3.x

I want to just understand why the below code is not very good at removing duplicates:

```
numbers = [4, 4, 4, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 2]
for duplicates in numbers:
    numbers.count(duplicates)
    if numbers.count(duplicates) > 1:
        numbers.remove(duplicates)
numbers.sort()
print(numbers)
```

The final output is: [2, 4, 10, 10, 20]

This could just be a fundamental error in my understanding of the methods used, but I would like to know what is wrong here.

PS. I'm aware I could do an easier version of this code posted below, but I am just curious.

Easier version of above code:

```
numbers = [4, 4, 4, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 2]
unique_list = []
for duplicates_check in numbers:
    if duplicates_check not in unique_list:
        unique_list.append(duplicates_check)
unique_list.sort()
print(unique_list)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Modifying the list you are iterating over is a bad idea and leads to problems like this. You can just use `list(set(numbers))` as `set`s eliminate all duplicates by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the list as you're iterating over it is a bad idea (since the loop gets "confused" about which index it's on).

Since you're sorting the numbers in the end, you apparently don't care about the order.

Just do

```
numbers = sorted(set(numbers))
```

– that is, convert the numbers to a set; sets can only contain each element once, then use `sorted()` to sort the set into a new list.

If you would care about the order,

```
def unique_in_order(iterable):
    seen = set()
    for item in iterable:
        if item not in seen:
            seen.add(item)
            yield item

numbers = list(unique_in_order(iterable))
```

is your recipe.

Comment: I see. I was messing around with some basic tutorials on python and found this a little perplexing. Thank you so much for you help!